# Sumar valores de diferentes tablas y seleccionar el resultado mayor

Tags: mysql

Bueno tengo el siguiente problema  **Seleccionar el nombre del empleado cuyo sueldo más el sueldo extra de su puesto sea el mayor.** 
Y estas son mis 2 tablas:

## ______Tabla Puesto______

```
create table if not exists puesto(
id int auto_increment primary key,
nombre varchar(30),
extra double
);
```

## ____Tabla empleado_____

```
create table if not exists empleados(
id_ven int auto_increment primary key,
nombre char(30) not null,
puesto int,
tipo char(1),
sueldo double,
antiguedad int,
deducciones double,
sucursal int,
comisiones double,
total double as (sueldo - deducciones + comisiones),
constraint puesto_fk foreign key(puesto) references puesto(id),
constraint sucursal_pk foreign key (sucursal) references sucursales(id_suc)
);
```

Comment: Se me ocurre algo así: `SELECT e.nombre, MAX(SUM(e.total)+SUM(p.extra)) sueldo_neto FROM empleados e INNER JOIN puesto p ON e.puesto=p.id GROUP BY e.id_ven, e.nombre LIMIT 1`... aquí se asume que `total` representa lo que dice su alias. Esta consulta te devolverá  una sola fila, del que tenga mayor salario. Aunque cabe preguntarse ¿y si hubiera varios empleados con un `MAX(sueldo_neto)`
 que sea igual?